# I can't build Cordova against Android 4.1.1

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build my Android app against version 4.1.1 (Android 22) but I am stuck since almost 2 days, so I hope someone can help me:

I try to add the platform with this commmand:

```
➜  app cordova platform add android@4
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@4
Adding android project...
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Unhandled "error" event. (Does not appear to implement platform Api.)
Error: Unhandled "error" event. (The platform "android" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. android not supported.)
➜  app
```

Doesn't work :( I check my installed platforms:

```
➜  app cordova platforms
Installed platforms:
  .idea
  ios 4.5.4
Available platforms: 
  android ~6.3.0
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  browser ~5.0.0
  osx ~4.0.1
  ubuntu ~4.3.4 (deprecated)
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~5.0.0
  www ^3.12.0
```

In my Android Studio, I do have 22 installed. What's the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The new version of Cordova > 7.1.0 seems to include this ".idea" platform when you add android platform and upgrade gradle

Try running this on your terminal \ command prompt in your app directory

`ionic cordova platform rm .idea`